# Quarkus - CDI bean tree/graph

Tags: cdi, quarkus

I was wondering if there was a way using Quarkus to see how beans are being pulled in. Like a tree or graph showing the hierarchy of bean resolution. I have a few beans that I think should be considered "unused", but they are still pulled in (I know because they fail with missing config properties).

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting idea. Would you care to file a new issue here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues?

By the way, "unremovable" beans do not need to be injected anywhere. There are [other rules](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#whats-removed) that apply. For example, a `@Named` bean or a bean that declares an observer method is never removed. Furthermore, Quarkus extensions can add their own rules.

Answer (score 0):

Added enhancement issue to github: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/26065

PR: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/26153

Will be built to 2.11